# Are there two Kashyaps

Tags: history, rishi, evidence, kanada, kashyapa

Kashyapa is one of the Saptarishis to whom several important texts such as the Kashyapa Samhita (on Ayurveda) is attributed.

Then there is Kanada, who is the father of the Vaisheshika school of Hindu philosophy, who came up with the idea of atoms, in the Vaisheshika Sutra. Kanada is also known as Kashyapa.

I was wondering if the two are the same person or are they different people who just happen to have the same name? What are the possible time frames of their lives on the basis of evidence?

Answer (score -1):

Kanaada seems like a derogatory term used by the spiritualist opponents of the materialistic Vaisheshika Philosophy. Spiritualists became prominent later. Saankhya and Vaisheshika are the oldest Darshanas of Vedas. Indians should celebrate Kashyapa or Kanaada as the first proponent of the Atomic Theory in the world.